# How to copy Word to Array of bytes?

Tags: delphi

How to copy Word to Array of bytes?

Comment: do not use string when you want to write binary. Array of byte would be a better choice...

Comment: I read Remy's answer to your previous question. It is the only correct way to do this (record + binary). I don't understand why you don't want to take good advice...

Comment: sorry I did not downvote...

Comment: If you want to store a `WideString` in a file, the best approach is to encode it to UTF8 first (via `UTF8Encode()`), then store that instead. You can put a UTF-8 string into an `AnsiString` (`UTF8String` is literally just an alias for `AnsiString` in D7), or in a byte array. Then, just reverse the process when reading the file. Read the UTF-8 first, then decode it (via `UTF8Decode() `) back to a `WideString`.

Comment: What makes you think readers could be bothered to downvote your q for revenge?  Revenge isn't part of the SO ethos.  Write better qs and the number of downvotes will go down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Move` to copy bytes

```
Move(wordValue, header[3], SizeOf(wordValue));
```

But `AnsiString` is the wrong data type. This is binary data, use an array of `Byte`.

Comment: The sooner you realise that not all data is text, and start using the correct data types, the sooner your life will become easier and you'll not have to ask one question after another about how to force square pegs into round holes.

Comment: Move is not a function. And why cast to PWideChar. Why are you obsessed with text?

Comment: As David said, there is absolutely no need to cast to `WideChar`. Just do: `w := length(header) + offsetSize; Move(w, header[3], SizeOf(w));`. The cast to `WideChar` and even more, the cast to `PWideChar(wc)^` is wrong. `wc` is not a pointer, so you shouldn't cast it to one. And, as said it is unnecessary too. ISTM you don't fully understand what you are actually doing and at the same time have problems following advice.

Comment: Same problem as all your questions about stream Read and Write. str is a pointer.

Comment: Same problem again. data is also a pointer. You'll need to make sure that you allocate data with a SetLength call. No idea why you have binary data in a string yet again.

Comment: I think you need to take stock and gain some understanding here because it's a bad sign to make the same mistake over and over again.